# How to highlight where a number in another cell falls in a column? Bracket it with the next highest and next lowest?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

This is probably an easy fix. I have one cell (Cell B8) with say the number 2000 in it. I have another column of 6 numbers (Cell A1 to A6) (Say 4000, 3050, 2100,2100, 1150, 200) that will change with market data. I want to highlight where the number from Cell B8 will fall in the column (A1 to A5). Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you want this to look? What is the expected result with your data sample? Highlight what? How?

Comment: @teylyn , looking to highlight the next highest and next lowest. In my example above i would want the 2100 and the 1150 to be highlighted so that i know my 2000 number from cell B8 would fall in their. The column will be based on quartiles of a larger data set with the median and the average in their as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try conditional formatting on cells A1 to A6 using this formula:

=OR(ROW(A1)=MATCH($B$8,$A$1:$A$6,-1),ROW(A1)=MATCH($B$8,$A$1:$A$6,-1)+1)

You will need to adjust the Match and the Row(A1) part to suit your actual workbook locations. If you let me know what the real rows are, I can add this to the post.

[image]

Comment: Sweet formula thank you. I was able to adjust your formula to

Comment: @ teylyn one thing is that if my metric is out of the range too high on your image above (how do paste in to these comment boxes any way?) say 5000 then nothing gets highlighted. Is there a way around that? I will try and post a picture of what I have. Any way thak you for your help so far, very much appreciated

Comment: Well, as far as I understand you want to highlight the range BETWEEN which the value falls. 5000 is not between any of the values, so nothing gets highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:  On Conditional Formatting click on New Rule, then Format all cells based on their value.  For Minimum click on Type: and select Number. For value click the little window on the right and select cell B8.  Do the same for Maximum.  Select different colors for Minimum and Maximum, if you're so inclined.  The cells in A1-A6 will change highlighting.  Those greater than B8 will have one highlight, and those less another.

Comment: Thanks @billoer , that worked well. I need to take this one step further so see if this makes sense. I dont want any of the other numbers highlighted. In the exapmle i posted above I want jsut the next neumber up and the next number down (or even the closest number) to highlight. Have you run into that before?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be
to conditionally format the entire range (`A1:A6`) with the formula

```
=AND(A1>=B$8, B$8>=A2)
```

which checks, in a somewhat imprecise way,
whether the current cell (nominally `A1`) is the upper bracket;
i.e., if the current cell is ≥ `B$8` **and** the next cell down is below `B$8`. 
Then add a new rule to the range except for the top cell (i.e., `A2:A6`)
using *the exact same formula*:

[image]

Since this is interpreted relative to `A2`,
it tests whether the current cell is the lower bracket:

[image]

If `B8` is less than `A6` but ≥ 0,
then this will highlight `A6` as the upper bracket, so long as `A7` is blank. 
To mark `A1` as the lower bracket if `B8`,
add a rule to `A1` to format it if `=B$8>=A1`.

My answer does not work as well as teylyn’s
if one or more of the `A1:A6` range is equal to `B8`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Scott , very much appreciate your help. I wil try this in the am.